# Python Regex: How to select lines between two patterns

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, nlp

Consider a typical live chat data as follows:

```
Peter (08:16): 
Hi 
What's up? 
;-D

Anji Juo (09:13): 
Hey, I'm using WhatsApp!

Peter (11:17):
Could you please tell me where is the feedback?

Anji Juo (19:13): 
I don't know where it is. 

Anji Juo (19:14): 
Do you by any chance know where I can catch a taxi ?
```

To convert this raw text file to a DataFrame,  I need to write some regex to identify column names and then extract corresponding values.

Please see https://regex101.com/r/X3ubqF/1

```
Index(time)     Name        Message
08:16           Peter       Hi 
                            What's up? 
                            ;-D
09:13           Anji Juo    Hey, I'm using WhatsApp!
11:17           Peter       Could you please tell me where is the feedback?
19:13           Anji Juo    I don't know where it is. 
19:14           Anji Juo    Do you by any chance know where I can catch a taxi ?
```

The regex `r"(?P<Name>.*?)\s*\((?P<Index>(?:\d|[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d)\)"` can extract the values of the time and name columns perfectly, but I have no idea how to highlight and extract messages from a specific sender for each time index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `re` module to parse the string ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/x54r02/1)):

```py
import re

s = """
Peter (08:16): 
Hi 
What's up? 
;-D

Anji Juo (09:13): 
Hey, I'm using WhatsApp!

Peter (11:17):
Could you please tell me where is the feedback?

Anji Juo (19:13): 
I don't know where it is. 

Anji Juo (19:14): 
Do you by any chance know where I can catch a taxi ?

"""


all_data = []
for part in re.findall(
    r"^\s*(.*?)\s+\(([^)]+)\):\s*(.*?)(?:\n\n|\Z)", s, flags=re.M | re.S
):
    all_data.append(part)

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data, columns=["Index(time)", "Name", "Message"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Index(time)   Name                                                      Message
0       Peter  08:16                                        Hi \nWhat's up? \n;-D
1    Anji Juo  09:13                                     Hey, I'm using WhatsApp!
2       Peter  11:17              Could you please tell me where is the feedback?
3    Anji Juo  19:13                                   I don't know where it is. 
4    Anji Juo  19:14  Do you by any chance know where I can catch a taxi ?\n\n
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
(?m)^(?P<user>.*?)\s*\((?P<hhmm>(?:\d|[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d)\):\s*(?P<Quote>.*(?:\n(?!\n).*)*)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/1tIsa7/1).

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##ZZFNTsMwEEb3OcXQTeOojRrKb4BGFV1QJKSyYlEXyU2mtWliR7ajEok7sGbFFblBcApFIBbj0Vjf85PGZW25ksOmEUWptAWNnmfgCjoztKjBH5zF0QmJgcob4Y4HzmzXQFUmbrjoT6ikciyfBNxWyoXP42j4Fca6B9NuAZURcg0tZsZledDmv1@Oojg6JTGV16rKM6hVBWWOzCBYzHMoELYcNYIwYDnCCjFbsnST/FVGP8opZEp2LWyk2u5R6@gQ/hNHO2KidtZlDUzWkHImU/yNTyFl0pVNOTCw7FmAs3@8v73ui8qO52lc47Nbme48@snssjKoR2GQEGoC6rc3nBfFyE9imr3MB9HCtcP5oD9ckNi1YzcT6vZggjZ7XymLDm/j0k/cwkgYkIA4T6mFtL7GcCVkxvLc34l7YHru18I7Qrym@QQ)**:

```py
import re

s = "Peter (08:16): \nHi \nWhat's up? \n;-D\n\nAnji Juo (09:13): \nHey, I'm using WhatsApp!\n\nPeter (11:17):\nCould you please tell me where is the feedback?\n\nAnji Juo (19:13): \nI don't know where it is. \n\nAnji Juo (19:14): \nDo you by any chance know where I can catch a taxi ?\n\n"

regex = r"^(?P<user>.*?)\s*\((?P<hhmm>(?:\d|[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d)\):\s*(?P<Quote>.*(?:\n(?!\n).*)*)"

print(re.findall(regex, s, re.M))
```

**Results**:

```
[('Peter', '08:16', "Hi \nWhat's up? \n;-D"), ('Anji Juo', '09:13', "Hey, I'm using WhatsApp!"), ('Peter', '11:17', 'Could you please tell me where is the feedback?'), ('Anji Juo', '19:13', "I don't know where it is. "), ('Anji Juo', '19:14', 'Do you by any chance know where I can catch a taxi ?\n\n')]
```

**EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?m)                     set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                           matching start and end of line) (case-
                           sensitive) (with . not matching \n)
                           (matching whitespace and # normally)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<user>                   group and capture to "user" group:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the least amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of "user" group
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                       '('
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (hhmm                     group and capture to "hmm" group:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [01]                     any character of: '0', '1'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      2                        '2'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [0-3]                    any character of: '0' to '3'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [0-5]                    any character of: '0' to '5'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of "hhmm" group
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                       ')'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<Quote>                 group and capture to "Quote" group:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        \n                       '\n' (newline)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of "Quote" group
```